# chartJS doesn't show graphs on iphone/ipad

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, chart.js

i have built a website running on a local host that draw graphs according to data from a data base.
chartJS works fine on my computer but doesn't show graphs on iphone/ipad,i dont have android device around me to check if it  works on android.
if someone have an idea how solving this please help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you use an old version of IOS where the resize observer is available. Chart.js V3 uses this so you will either need to polyfill it or use V2 to show the charts.

Here is a pollyfill for the resize observer: https://github.com/juggle/resize-observer.

For more information you can see this [github issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/8414)

Comment: im using sfari 15 , and i tried to add  a cdn of the resize observer still cant see nothing on mobile devices